# Generating Mouse events in C++ / Processing on Windows (Emulate Mouse)

Tags: windows, winapi, processing, device-driver, mousemove

I have a proprietary device connected via An arduino microprocessor to USB, which I want to use as a Mouse emulator. At present I use a processing (language) program to generate x,y data pertaining to mouse coordinates.

I'm looking for a way to emulate the mouse, so that a application such as a game which uses the mouse pointer can be used with my system, without altering the application.

I think this deals with Windows APIs ?. It is more like I want to know where I can find reference if I want to write a program which works as a mouse driver.

Answer (score 0):

[Mouse event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Cursor Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And if you so needed it: [Keyboard Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)